# With knitr and latex, how can you extract all references from the .Rnw script?

Tags: r, reference, latex, knitr

Running `knitr` and laTeX to create a PDF, what code allows you to extract all the references that are in the .Rnw script?

There seems to be no auxiliary file created for references like there are for the table of contents and list of figures.

Note: a separate question just posted on StackOverflow, asks about a solution using regex, but a problem that came up when trying to extract references that way.

Thank you.

Is there a way with R to find and pull out the latex references?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution in R (probably a faster solution exists in non-R).

```
# read Rnw as a single character string
r <- paste(readLines("myfile.Rnw"), collapse="")

# Extract the citep fields (assuming you used natbib)
# Do something similar for citet
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(r, "citep[{][[:alnum:]]+[}]")
```

Then all you have to do is remove the citep stuff with `gsub`.

Comment: Thanks.  When I wrote "references" I meant \ref{} type references (cross references, perhaps, is the better description).  Will your solution work the same, substituting ref for citep?

Comment: Your solution did not work when I ran str_extract_all(r, "ref[{][[:alnum:]]+[}]").  Any suggestions?